# Cloudant / CouchDB add new view to existing design document through Java client(API)

Tags: java, nosql, couchdb, cloudant

I am working on an existing Java application with Cloudant database which has a design document defined with 4 views. I want to add one more new view to this.

From the existing Java client code the way it is done is - Delete existing design document(`database.getDesignDocumentManager().remove`) and create new design document which now also has the new view(`database.save`)

Is this the way to do it? Because I feel why should the existing design doc./views be deleted when we are just adding another. Won't this be a overhead or time consuming task if there are many documents?

Anyways if there is a better way then please let me know with Java API's to achieve this.

Comment: Can't you just push the new version of the document?

Comment: Its a document so yes I can push/save/put, but this is a design doc.so I am not sure of how the views in the document will be processed / time it takes as I have thousands of docs to which the view applies?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but [as documented](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#view-functions), whenever you update one view, all views within the same ddoc are rebuilt.

Comment: So, I guess that's why we already have delete + re-create.. ok will try to save new ddoc and see impact. Thanks @Flimzy

Comment: delete + recreate will be disruptive in a way that pushing a new doc isn't, as there is a time that the views will be completely broken/non-existant.

Comment: Thats why this is handled in init of application. Just want to keep the init time minimal.